# I'm not able to get the output for the following code

Tags: c++

I want to print the numbers like this:

```
1| 2| 3| 4|
5| 6| 7| 8|
9| 10| 11| 12|
13| 14| 15| 16|
```

So, I'm using a code like this:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
#include<cstdlib>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<time.h>
#define GRID_SIZE 4

using namespace std;

class Game {
 private:
  char grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
 public:
  void generateGrid();
  void showGrid();
  Game();
};

void Game::generateGrid() {
  int n = 1;
  for( int x=0; x<GRID_SIZE; x++) {
    for( int y= 0; y<GRID_SIZE; y++) {
      grid[x][y] = to_string(n).c_str()[0];
      n++;
    }
  }
}

void Game::showGrid() {
  printf("------------\n");
  for(int x=0; x<GRID_SIZE; x++) {
    for(int y=0; y<GRID_SIZE; y++) {
      cout<< " " << grid[x][y] << " |";
    }
    cout << "\n------------\n";
  }
}
 
Game::Game() {
  generateGrid();
  showGrid();
}

int main() {
  Game game;
}
```

I have used to_string(number).c_str()[0];
to convert it into char data type. So that I can change that afterwards.

But here, the output I'm receiving is like:

```
1| 2| 3| 4|
5| 6| 7| 8|
9| 1| 1| 1|
1| 1| 1| 1|
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the problem is here

```
char grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

You are saying that the grid consists of **single characters only**.

Since you want the grid to be made of numbers, why didn't you write this?

```
int grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

and this

```
grid[x][y] = n;
n++;
```

If you really want the grid to be multiple characters then you need `string` not `char`, like this

```
string grid[GRID_SIZE][GRID_SIZE];
```

and this

```
grid[x][y] = to_string(n);
n++;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is at this line:

```
grid[x][y] = to_string(n).c_str()[0];
```

You only save one char and when n > 10:

```
n = 10
to_string(n) => "10"
to_string(n).c_str()[0] => "1";
```

You is getting the first element of the string and this bug occurs when generating your grid. John's response above is a great way to solve your problem.